# Refresh datatable using RefreshApex in LWC

Tags: lightning-web-components, lightning-datatable, refreshapex

I am new to LWC. I have questions regarding `refreshApex`. I was not able to find answers in the official documentation or other sites.

1) How does `refreshApex` know which datatable to refresh if there are two datatables? Is it through `wiredProperty`?

2) Does `refreshApex` run the whole code of wire method everytime it refreshes data?

Eg: In my LWC, I need to flatten the data before displaying it using lightning datatable. Refresh works in this case too but I am not able to understand how. Does it run the whole code of wire again?

```js
@wire(getAddress, { LeadID: '$recordId' }) wired(result) {
    this.refreshTable = result;
    if (result.data) {
        let preparedAddresses = [];
        result.data.forEach(address => {
            let preparedAddress = {};
            preparedAddress.Account_Id = address.AccountId.Id;
            preparedAddress.Account_Name = address.AccountId.Name;
            preparedAddress.Contact_Name = address.ContactID.Name;
            preparedAddresses.push(preparedAddress);
        });
        this.addresses = preparedAddresses;
    }
}

handleSuccess() {
            return refreshApex(this.refreshTable);
    }
```

Comment: The component’s JavaScript prefaces the value of the parameter with $ to indicate that it’s dynamic and reactive. It references a property of the component instance. If its value changes, the template rerenders. Refresh apex does the refresh of data from server. Refresh of datatable is a driven by reactive properties of your LWC. Now about wire  the property decorated with @wire is used as an attribute in the template and if its value changes, the wire service provisions the data and triggers the component to rerender. The wiring also determine which datatable to refresh. 

.